# htaccess url rewriting from /mydir/subdir/page to /mydir-subdir-page

Tags: php, .htaccess

What regular expression need to use for rewriting url having in input something as:

```
http://domain.ext/mydir/subdir/page.php
```

and in output something as:

```
http://domain.ext/mydir-subdir-page.php
```

The "mydir" is a constant. "subdir" and "page" are variables.
I have tried with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/mydir/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ /mydir/$1-$2.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

but don't work. Thanks.

Comment: Of course it won’t work if `mydir/` is the beginning of the path, but your pattern demands there be letters and a slash _before_ it …

Comment: I am not much practise with regular expression, can you tell me please as need fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing the rewrite to only occur if there alphanumeric characters before `/mydir/` which will never happen.

**Edit:** Assuming from your comment that you wish to rewrite `/mydir-subdir-page.php` to `/mydir/subdir/page.php`, update your rewrite as follows

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/mydir-([^/]+)-([^/]+).php$ /mydir/$1/$2.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Trying so don't work :( Trying give url in format:  /mydir-subdir-page.php return me page not found.

Comment: Your question is unclear in that case then. Your rewrite is the wrong way around.

Comment: Sorry, i am little confused. With a example in input i have: "http://www.mydomain.ext/mydir/subdir/page.php" and i want which htaccess redirect to: "http://www.mydomain.ext/mydir-subdir-page.php" just converting slash in dash starting from "/mydir". I have tried with your example but nothing :( When i give url with dash return page not found.

Comment: So you actually want it to redirect, rather than rewrite?